# How to insert a xml file with a variable into SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a procedure that gets an xml file and inserts its values into a table in my database. I want have an insert that inserts both xml file and a new variable

Something like this:

```
create procedure spxml @exml xml
as
   declare @code int
   set @code=1
   begin
    insert into empxml(EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName) 
    values (
       select 
          Col.value('EmployeeID[1]','Int'),
          Col.value('FirstName[1]','Nvarchar(50)'),
          Col.value('LastName[1]','Nvarchar(50)')
       From 
          @exml.nodes('/DocumentElement/Row') tmp(Col),@code)
end
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
insert empxml(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName, Code) 
select 
Col.value('EmployeeID[1]','Int') ,    
Col.value('FirstName[1]','Nvarchar(50)'),
Col.value('LastName[1]','Nvarchar(50)'),
@code
From @exml.nodes('/DocumentElement/Row') tmp(Col)
```